# Formula to put any value like 99 in place of 0 in a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I want to put a value 888 as given in excel screenshot in place of 0

I'm already using the Vlookup formula in given column so find/replace isn't working.

[image]

Comment: Unless the numbers in `Length` are inserted by a formula, to do this in place without disrupting the values in the other cells, it will take vba.  If they are by formula then please show the formula currently there.

Comment: A formula won't replace existing text in a cell. Use find/replace instead

Comment: Click on the link above my name the one that starts with `edited..` and you will see what I changed.  But I do not believe you can till you gain rep.

Comment: Not able to catch that.
Can you show a little example

Comment: Want to use formula for that instead of using find/replace

Comment: Is there currently a formula in that column?  If not vba is the only way to go.  If so, [edit] your post to include the formula currently in the cells.

Comment: Last attempt: Please post the actual formula being used.  we cannot modify a formula that we cannot see.

Comment: =ABS(VLOOKUP(C19,'Nodal Information'!A:C,3,0)-VLOOKUP(B19,'Nodal Information'!A:C,3,0))

Answer (score 1):

Test for `0` and if so return the cell with the default:

```
IF(ABS(VLOOKUP(C19,'Nodal Information'!A:C,3,0)-VLOOKUP(B19,'Nodal Information'!A:C,3,0))=0,H2,ABS(VLOOKUP(C19,'Nodal Information'!A:C,3,0)-VLOOKUP(B19,'Nodal Information'!A:C,3,0)))
```

Comment: Its return something else not that 888 value already defined in H2 cell

Comment: It should only return the value in `H2` when the output would be 0, otherwise it outputs the values returned from the vlookups()

Comment: That's great Scott. Answer is correctly applied


 But when I use drag feature to apply it for rest of the cell the reference given as H2 cell changes to H3 and H4 and so on. I want to keep the H2 reference constant


 Like for the other cell as well H2 will remain their for the other cell as well not H3, H4.....

Comment: then make it absolute `$H$2`